# NullReferenceException in SimpleInjector.Container.Verify when instancing view via XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, simple-injector

I'm still in the process of getting into WPF and also decided to give Simple Injector a spin. I created a very simple test project based on the [WPF integration example provided in the Simple Injector documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wpfintegration.html). My current code is pretty much identical to that example or arguably even simpler as I do not yet have any service objects.

What is different is that I do have a simple View with an accompanying ViewModel that is currently the only thing that is on the `MainWindow`:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfPlayground.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfPlayground"
            xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfPlayground.View"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MyApp" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <view:MyView />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

My `MainWindowViewModel` class exists but is currently still empty. Its constructor has no parameters.

This is what I have so far of `MyView` (the XAML is still just an empty `<Grid />`):

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView(MyViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = myViewModel;
    }
}
```

This is the `Bootstrap()` method from my `Program` class:

```
        private static Container Bootstrap()
        {
            var container = new Container();

            container.Register<MainWindow>();
            container.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
            container.Register<MyView>();
            container.Register<MyViewModel>();

            container.Verify();

            return container;
        }
```

Now, I get a `NullReferenceException` inside the `MainWindow` constructor when `InitializeComponent()` is called ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object"). The call stack points back to the call to `container.Verify()` in `Program.Bootstrap()` (see above). The constructors of neither `MyViewModel` nor `MyView` are ever reached.

If I were to take a guess I'd say that the application is not going through the `Container` to get the instance of `MyView`. One of the reasons I did this experiment was actually because I was interested to see how Simple Injector would accomplish this as the documentation seemed to imply that this would somehow happen automatically. Could it be there is a step missing from the documentation? Something to register some sort of interceptor? Is this maybe not the right way to use Simple Injector with WPF/XAML after all? Hopefully I won't have to create controls in code?

Comment: The best (and probably only) way to diagnose an error like this is to get the source code for Simple Injector, add it to your solution and step through the Verify call.

Comment: Yep, thanks! I just found this: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/151 - which appears to be exactly my issue. Not yet sure how I feel about the suggested solution...

Comment: That issue has an actual error message: "The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type MainWindow failed."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, now you mention it... That is actually the outer exception in my case as well. The `NullReferenceException` was just the first one I hit when running this in the Debugger. Sorry for the incomplete info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I were to take a guess I'd say that the application is not going through the Container to get the instance of MyView

Yes, SimpleInjector is *not* able to resolve a view that you define inline in the XAML markup like this.

When the `InitializeComponent()` method is called at runtime, the built-in parser tries to create an instance of the view that you have defined in your XAML markup wihout any knowledge about or reference to any container.

So your code fails when trying to resolve an instance of the `MainWindow`, because an exception is thrown from the call to `InitializeComponent()` in its constructor.

The example in the docs that you refer to doesn't define any inline views. This only works for views that have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: OK, understood. So how would you resolve this? As I said, I just started with WPF and composing windows of nested views is just how all my colleagues (I justed started in this company) are doing it (they do not yet have a standardised DI framework which is why I'm evaluating Simple Injector). Would you second the suggestions from this GitHub-issue (https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/151) to essentially construct the views in code and then bind them to a `<ContentControl>`? - or would you not use nested views (with Simple Injector) at all?

Comment: Nested views should generally speaking inherit their `DataContext` from the parent element. They shouldn't be injected with view models.